# Problem with setting background of UINavBar background

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am using the following code to set the background of the UINavBar

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.contents=(id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"topbar-nonretina.png"].CGImage;
```

However, sometimes I am getting the following error :

```
property `contents` not found on object of type `CALayer`
```

Can anyone kindly tell me whats happening here ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably cause you're not including **QuartzCore** in some file.

```
#include <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

**CALayer** is defined there, so if you don't include that file, the compiler doesn't know that the layer property of *navigationBar* has a *contents* property itself